# CSS - How to set a nested div against body bottom? (Image included)

Tags: css, layout

How can I achieve the styling shown in the picture? Consindering the following scenario: I got 2 nested div elements, by which the parent is "relative positioned" and the child is "absolute positioned"! And the child div is always "fixed to the bottom" of the body element, when browser is scaled. I don't get this to work...

[image]

Here is the code, where I am using padding-bottom: 100%. But this is not a good solution! Is there a way to realise this with only CSS 2.1 API?

```css
 body {
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
}

.parent {
    height: 70px;
    width: 440px;
    left:200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
} 

.child {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    right:0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Fix to bottom</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show your code to us

Comment: Here you got the code. I am thankful for any kind of help...

Answer (score 0):

Don't take 2nd div as child. You want it to stick to bottom and parent div's height will disturb it while scalling.

I hope this helps :)

```css
body {
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
}

.parent {
    height: 70px;
    width: 400px;
    left:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top:70px;
} 

.another-parent {
    display: block;
    height:60%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0; 
    width: 100px;
    right:22%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent"></div>
    <div class="another-parent">Fix to bottom</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think my issue is a result of bad css layout design... I can't get this working... Unfortunately, I am on a CSS project which is very restrictive in layouting... Thanx anyway...